# Флаг IsMessageComplete вызывает ошибку в клиенте

Tags: c#, pipes

Я пишу эту программу на C# с использованием .NET Framework 4.7.1 (последняя на момент написания вопроса). На стороне с NamedPipeServerStream всё в порядке, работает так, как надо. У вот у клиентов чтение/запись работают, но не работает флаг IsMessageComplete. Получаю: `"Исключение   Возникло исключение "System.InvalidOperationException" в System.Core.dll ("ReadMode не принадлежит к PipeTransmissionMode.Message.")"`. Я пробовал клиенту давать флаг "PipeTransmissionMode.Message", но он ругается `"Дескриптор канала не задан.  Совершила ли реализация PipeStream вызов InitializeHandle?"`, а этой функции даже нет в классе PipeStream + неужели клиенту для работы надо передавать дескриптор сервера (он не передаётся сам?)? Ещё один pipe делать что ли?

Код объявления сервера:
`NamedPipeServerStream npserver = new NamedPipeServerStream("pipe1", PipeDirection.InOut, 5, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.Asynchronous, 128, 128);`
Код объявления клиента:
`NamedPipeClientStream plc = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "pipe1", PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);`
Вот класс работы с клиентом (код работы с сервером такой же, но заменены `NamedPipeClientStream` на `NamedPipeServerStream`):

```
class StreamOperations
    {
        public StreamOperations(ref NamedPipeClientStream server)
        {
            this.server = server;
        }
        byte[] buffer1 = new byte[128];
        byte count;
        string str;
        volatile NamedPipeClientStream server;
        public byte RQ1_Read()
        {
            count = (byte)server.Read(buffer1, 0, buffer1.Length);
            str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer1, 0, count);
            return count;
        }
        public byte RQ1_ReadBig()
        {
            byte[] str = new byte[0];
            count = (byte)server.Read(buffer1, 0, buffer1.Length);
            str = str.Concat(buffer1.Take(count)).ToArray();
            while (!server.IsMessageComplete) //Тут в клиенте возникает ошибка
            {
                count = (byte)server.Read(buffer1, 0, buffer1.Length);
                str = str.Concat(buffer1.Take(count)).ToArray();
            }
            this.str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(str, 0, str.Length);
            return (byte)(count == 0 ? 0 : 1);
        }
        public string RQ2_KString()
        {
            return str;
        }
        public void Write(string str)
        {
            server.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str), 0, str.Length);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обратившись к форуму, нашёл ответ на свой вопрос!

> А Ларчик просто открывался.

Нужно было прописать `plc.ReadMode = PipeTransmissionMode.Message;` после `plc.Connect(1000);`.
Вот и всё!